# A weird string literal identity issue in Django

Tags: python, django

I have an API in the Django project I am working on that sends commands to devices. The API expects a POST request with data containing something like `{"command": "activate"}`. A few minutes ago I found this bit of code in the view function for the API

```
... ommitting the DRF viewset class def for brevity ...
def command(self, request):
    if 'command' in request.data and request.data['command'] is not 'activate':
        ... do things that we need to do to send the activate command...
```

I figured that someone (most likely myself) made a logic error and fixed it to `request.data['command'] is 'activate'`, but immediately realized that the API actually works as is. That is this if statement evaluates as True and commands do get sent even though it clearly states `request.data['command'] is not 'activate'`

So I started debugging and eventually found out that `request.data['command'] != 'activate'` returns False as expected and breaks the code, but `request.data['command'] is not 'activate'` returns True. As far as I can tell, the difference between `is not` and `!=` is that `is not` compares identity where `!=` compares value. But, again, as far as I know, literals should have the same identity no matter where they come from. A quick test in ipython seems to confirm this

```
 In [1] x = {'command': 'activate'}
 In [2] x['command'] is 'activate'
 Out[2] True
 In [3] x['command'] is not 'activate'
 Out[3] False
```

What the hell is going on? Why doesn't it work in the view?

Comment: *literals should have the same identity no matter where they come from* isn't totally correct. That is strictly implementation dependent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not rely on string comparison by identity, in any cases.  The fact that it *appears to work sometimes* is due to an implementation detail of CPython called string interning.  The rules governing whether a given string will be interned or not are very complicated, and subject to change without notice.

For example, with a slight modification of your original example we can change the behaviour:

```
>>> x = {'command': 'activate.'}
>>> x['command'] is 'activate.'
False
```

**Use `==` and `!=` for string comparisons.**

Answer (score 0):

> But, again, as far as I know, literals should have the same identity no matter where they come from.

First, that's not actually true. Unlike, say, Java, Python makes no guarantees about whether literals are interned:

```
In [1]: x = 'a b'

In [2]: x is 'a b'
Out[2]: False
```

Second, the `'activate'` in `request.data['command']` is coming from a parsed network request, not a string literal.